# Filter function in a pipe won't filter

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I am brand new to R and having issues getting the right output from a pipe. My code is:

```
(filtered_toothgrowth <- ToothGrowth) %>%   
  filter(dose==0.5) %>% 
  group_by(supp)%>%
  summarize(mean_len = mean(len,na.rm = T), .group="drop")
```

I've already installed and used a library function to get tidyverse. I have parentheses in the first line because it wont print to the console with out them, although I've seen examples not using them but can't figure out how. The print result is a tibble when it should be a filtered table leading me to think something is wrong with my filter.

I've tried removing the parentheses but it wont print to console. I've tried using an arrange function to see if the filter would work and it did so I'm not sure why additional lines make it stop. The results I am getting look like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  supp  mean_len .group
  <fct>    <dbl> <chr> 
1 OJ       13.2  drop  
2 VC        7.98 drop
```

When it should be:

```
    len supp dose
1   4.2   VC  0.5
2   5.2   VC  0.5
3   5.8   VC  0.5
4   6.4   VC  0.5
5   7.0   VC  0.5
6   7.3   VC  0.5
7   8.2   OJ  0.5
8   9.4   OJ  0.5
9   9.7   OJ  0.5
10  9.7   OJ  0.5
11 10.0   VC  0.5
12 10.0   OJ  0.5
13 11.2   VC  0.5
14 11.2   VC  0.5
15 11.5   VC  0.5
16 14.5   OJ  0.5
17 15.2   OJ  0.5
18 16.5   OJ  0.5
19 17.6   OJ  0.5
20 21.5   OJ  0.5
```

Comment: If you remove the parentheses and just call the object name (in this case `filtered_toothgrowth`) after you run your chunk of code, it will display the object.

Comment: To see what you want, run `ToothGrowth %>% filter(dose==0.5)`

Comment: When you group and summarise it's going to summarise all unique groups into one row per group, since there is only OJ and VC in the group you supplied `supp` you'll get two rows returned with the mean value for `len`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and for editing my original question into a better looking format. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It happened because you pipe it into summarize() function, if you delete this, the result is coming. let's see:

```
> (filtered_toothgrowth <- ToothGrowth) %>%   
+   filter(dose==0.5) %>% 
+   group_by(supp)
# A tibble: 20 × 3
# Groups:   supp [2]
     len supp   dose
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
 1   4.2 VC      0.5
 2  11.5 VC      0.5
 3   7.3 VC      0.5
 4   5.8 VC      0.5
 5   6.4 VC      0.5
 6  10   VC      0.5
 7  11.2 VC      0.5
 8  11.2 VC      0.5
 9   5.2 VC      0.5
10   7   VC      0.5
11  15.2 OJ      0.5
12  21.5 OJ      0.5
13  17.6 OJ      0.5
14   9.7 OJ      0.5
15  14.5 OJ      0.5
16  10   OJ      0.5
17   8.2 OJ      0.5
18   9.4 OJ      0.5
19  16.5 OJ      0.5
20   9.7 OJ      0.5
>
```

Comment: If you don't use `group_by(supp)` then it's a tibble: 60*3